# SQL - Select first 10 rows only?

Tags: sql

How do I select only the first 10 results of a query?

I would like to display only the first 10 results from the following query:

```
SELECT a.names,
         COUNT(b.post_title) AS num
    FROM wp_celebnames a
    JOIN wp_posts b ON INSTR(b.post_title, a.names) > 0
    WHERE b.post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY a.names
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Comment: Please mention the database (and version).

Comment: Should be the new answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476971/124486

Comment: Also try TOP 10

Answer (score 241, accepted):

In SQL server, use:

```
select top 10 ...
```

e.g.

```
select top 100 * from myTable
select top 100 colA, colB from myTable
```

In MySQL, use:

```
select ... order by num desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 71):

Depends on your RDBMS

MS SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 10 ...
```

MySQL and PostgreSQL 8.3 or older:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 10
```

Sybase (>v15 ASE support TOP too)

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
SELECT ...
```

Etc.

Comment: The ... LIMIT 10 syntax is also used by sqlite3

Comment: `LIMIT 10` is also used by PostgreSQL

Answer (score 40):

The ANSI SQL answer is `FETCH FIRST`.

```
SELECT a.names,
         COUNT(b.post_title) AS num
    FROM wp_celebnames a
    JOIN wp_posts b ON INSTR(b.post_title, a.names) > 0
    WHERE b.post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY a.names
ORDER BY num DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

If you want ties to be included, do `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS WITH TIES` instead.

To skip a specified number of rows, use `OFFSET`, e.g.

```
...
ORDER BY num DESC
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Will skip the first 20 rows, and then fetch 10 rows.

Supported by newer versions of [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [Mimer SQL](https://docs.mimer.com/MimerSqlManual/v110/html/Manuals/select/select.htm#IX_FETCH_FIRST), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-offset-fetch/) and [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=subselect-fetch-clause) etc.

Note that with SQL Server, you must always specify `OFFSET` when using `FETCH FIRST`. (Should be optional according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.)

Comment: Just to make it clearer: The first query is not supported by MS SQL. It only works with the usage of the offset.

Answer (score 34):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What's the difference between limit 0, 10 and limit 10? And why doesn't limit 10, 20 give me 10 rows between the 10th and 20th rows?

EDIT: Oh, so limit 10, 20 means give me 20 rows after the 10th row. If I want rows between 10 and 20 I have to do limit 10, 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

In standard SQL you can use:

`... FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY`

This is supported in DB2, PostgreSQL and Oracle 12.1 (and later)

Comment: for PostgreSQL too

Answer (score 23):

Oracle

```
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10  and whatever_else ;
```

`ROWNUM` is a magic variable which contains each row's sequence number 1..*n*.

Comment: This is wrong. "rownum" will fetch the top 'n' rows from the table. It will not filter from "whatever_else" condition!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874082/show-only-the-first-n-lines-of-output-of-a-sql-query 
Please follow the answer by stili for Oracle related DB

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT a.names,
         COUNT(b.post_title) AS num
    FROM wp_celebnames a
    JOIN wp_posts b ON INSTR(b.post_title, a.names) > 0
    WHERE b.post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY a.names
ORDER BY num DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *  
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY user_id) user_row_no, a.* FROM temp_emp a)  
 WHERE user_row_no > 1 and user_row_no <11
```

This worked for me.If i may,i have few useful dbscripts that you can have look at

[Useful Dbscripts](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/09/db-scripts.html)

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT [num] OFFSET [num];
```

Comment: Limit is first answer but problem with Limit is, if you have 100,000 record and you want to fetch 10 with limit, it will still take whole time to fetch 100,000 record then will apply limit. so this way sql query get slower for larger record. thats why we are looking for alternate of limit.

Answer (score 2):

Firebird:

```
SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Top(12) Month, Year, Code FROM TempEmp 
ORDER BY  Year DESC,month DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT* from <table name> WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: according to here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

This is a listed answer for Oracle.. Up vote.

Comment: This will get you 10 rows, but if you have an "order by" clause, it won't work how you expect. rownum filtering happens before any order by or group by clauses, so you'll get 10 rows, which will then be grouped, or then be ordered. rather than grouping the rows, ordering them how you expect and then giving you first 10 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-2E40EC12-3FCF-4A4F-B5F2-6BC669021726