# How to insert max 3 results in different columns?

Tags: mysql, max

I would like to insert max 3 results of a column into 3 different columns.

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    m.top_marks 
FROM
    table_name t,
    (SELECT
         marks
     FROM table_name
     WHERE rownum <=3
     ORDER BY marks DESC) m
GROUP BY column_name DESC;
```

This can help me to get top 3 marks right? but what if i want to store top 3 results in 3 new columns? Marks1, marks2, marks3?

Comment: [Pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)? I imagine you may need to add something like a row-number field for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I really understand what you are going for... But it sounds like you might want the LIMIT operator. See this:

[SQL - Select first 10 rows only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only)

So maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    m.top_marks 
FROM
    table_name t,
    (SELECT
         marks
     FROM table_name
     ORDER BY marks DESC
     LIMIT 3) m
GROUP BY column_name DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` method:

```
SELECT t.name,
       substring_index(m.marks, ',', 1) as Mark1,
       substring_index(substring_index(m.marks, ',', 2), ',', -1) as Mark2,
       substring_index(substring_index(m.marks, ',', 3), ',', -1) as Mark3
    m.top_marks 
FROM table_name t cross join
     (SELECT group_concat(marks order by marks desc) as marks
      FROM table_name
     ) m
GROUP BY column_name DESC;
```

If it is sufficient to have them in one column with commas separating the values:

```
SELECT t.name, substring_index(m.marks, ',', 3) as Marks3
FROM table_name t cross join
     (SELECT group_concat(marks order by marks desc) as marks
      FROM table_name
     ) m
GROUP BY column_name DESC;
```