# List of the top 3 most ordered products - SQL

Tags: sql, list

I'd like to know a solution to listing the top 3 or so most ordered products in a database, as a basic example.

I currently know how to list in Ascending/Descending order but I do not know how to display the most popular orders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789

Comment: in sql server `select top 3 * from table order by count(*) desc `

Answer (score 1):

Well, without seeing your database model, this is pure conjecture. I'll give it a shot any way.

Let's say you have two tables: one for products and another for orders.

Products is:

```
Product_ID
Product_Name
Product_Price
```

Orders is:

```
Order_ID
Product_ID
Order_Date
```

You can do something like:

```
select Product_ID, count(Product_ID) as OrderCount
from Orders
group by Product_ID
order by OrderCount desc
```

This will give you the order count for each product. You can then filter down the list to however many you want to actually display.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this through your "orders" table by grouping by product_key and selecting top 3
if you want a more detailed/useful answer post ur DB structure but this is an example of what I mean

```
select top 3 , count(*) from orders group_by product_key order by count(*) DESC
```