# MySql: Select the first row from group, with INNER JOIN between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

To provide more info to my question, modify the inserted image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IuID.jpg

```
SELECT pro.id
     , pro.featured
     , pro.price_per_night
     , pro.meta_title
     , img.image
  FROM properties AS pro
  INNER JOIN images AS img 
    ON pro.id = img.imageable_id
 WHERE pro.featured = 1
```

With this query, all images that meet the query are displayed. That is, images are displayed: image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, and image9.

If I order LIMIT = 1, for example, only one image is displayed, more precisely the "image4". No more images are displayed.

I would like to change the query to display the first image of the fields that match the query. More precisely, I must show "image4" and "image7".

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Does the following question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only

Comment: Define 'first'!

Comment: By setting a LIMIT = 1, the query returns only one image. That is, only the first image that meets the same query conditions.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql limit](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
SELECT pro.id, pro.featured, pro.price_per_night, pro.meta_title, img.image
FROM properties AS pro 
INNER JOIN images AS img ON pro.id = img.imageable_id 
WHERE pro.featured = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a id to image and to get  first image  use `image_ID`.

```
SELECT pro.id
 , pro.featured
 , pro.price_per_night
 , pro.meta_title
 , img.image
```

`FROM properties AS pro`

`JOIN images AS img`

```
ON pro.id = img.imageable_id
```

`WHERE image_id=1`