# How to select top 20 values record from database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Employees`, each employees has a salary value. I want to select the top 20 employees based on salary.

My database columns look like this:

```
EMPLOYEE SALARY DEPARTMENT 
--------------------------
KARTHI   500     IT
MANO     500     ADMIN
SANDY    300     HR
KARTHI   400     IT
```

I want to get top records like this:

```
EMPLOYEE SALARY DEPARTMENT 
---------------------------
KARTHI   900     IT
MANO     500     ADMIN
SANDY    300     HR
```

How to get top 5 records from database like above?

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question you can easily get already posted answers for same question.

Comment: `select top 20 * from Employees order by salary`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Select first 10 rows only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only)

Comment: Top 5? 10? 20? Pick a value!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` window analytic function

```
select employee, salary, department 
  from
  (
   select e.*, row_number() over (order by e.salary desc) as rn
     from employees e
  ) e
 where rn <= 20;
```

If you have identical salaries(that's `ties`) for the boundary values such as the 20th-21st-22nd ranked people may have same salaries , then use :

```
select top 20 with ties employee, salary, department
  from employees 
 order by salary desc
```

to include all of the 22 people in the list. If you want to exclude 21st and 22nd people, then just use `select top 20 *` to ignore the ties.

Comment: `row_number` is kind of overkill for this.

Answer (score 1):

use top and order by salary desc

```
select top 20 EMPLOYEE, sum(SALARY) as salary, DEPARTMENT from 
tablename
group by employee,department
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: but employee should one time but shows repeated value also

Comment: Do you really think companies will give more than one salary for an employee ? or part of two departments

Comment: its posted sample data

Comment: @Pரதீப், I don't think it's possible in  real life but based on the op's data it seems to me that it happened :D

Comment: @PriyaRiya, could you please post the output which you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 E.* FROM EMP AS E ORDER BY E.SALARY DESC
```