# Replacing limit with top

Tags: sql, select, group-by, limit

If I have a simple query below as

```
select ID, sum(amount)
from table
where sum(amount) > 200
group by ID
limit 1
```

that gives me the ID with the highest total spend

if I am doing same in sql engine that does not except limit, but top how would I replace limit here with **top**?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only/36476971#36476971

Comment: Why not simply read the manual [of that SQL engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)