# Mysql - group showing all the data the last row by group

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is the following: How can I group in the table, but showing all the data the last row the group

**Query Table**

```
score  team    stadium            date
20     Ajax    Arena Stadium      '26/Feb/2020'
10     Madrid  Santiago Bernabeu  '26/Feb/2020'
10     Ajax    Arena Stadium      '22/Feb/2020'
```

**Expected result**

```
score  team    stadium            date
20     Ajax    Arena Stadium      '26/Feb/2020'
10     Madrid  Santiago Bernabeu  '26/Feb/2020'
```

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: How about `SELECT TOP 2 ...` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only/36476971?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT score, team, stadium, date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY score, team ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
) tbl
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: select team from myTable group by team   this is my attempt, but if your group it without considering score?