# Database agnostic query to fetch specific n number of records

Tags: java, sql, resultset, sql-limit, database-agnostic

I am looking for ways to run **SELECT * FROM TABLE** query across different databases.
To name a few : postgres, teradata, mysql, bigquery, redshift.
I want to find a way to parallelize this query so I can spawn multiple threads to read the data.
Each thread will read n number of records and dump it to a file(The number of records are parameterized).
**Example:**
Table1 has 200 records: spawn 4 threads each reading 50 records and writing to a separate file this giving us 4 files in total.
I have found about **LIMIT/OFFSET** but it is not generic enough to be used across these platforms.
I am using jdbc ResultSet.

Is there any way I can achieve this or do I have to write database specific implementations ?
The reason I need this I may have to deal with millions of records from a single table and I need to dump that to files limited by n number of records. So if I have 1mil records and my limit size is 200k I'll get 5 files as output.

Any kind of hint/suggestion/help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Check out Presto

Comment: @drum I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891789/sql-select-first-10-rows-only can perhaps be useful.